# Seaborn Example: Dot plot with several variables but with several Axis

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to plot the following example:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/pairgrid_dotplot.html

With a separate axis for every column. Currently the command:

```
g.set(xlim=(0, 25), xlabel="Crashes", ylabel="")
```

Sets one global axis range. How can I get an individual range? E.g. 0,25 for the first plot but 0,300 for the second?

Full code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

# Load the dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes")

# Make the PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(crashes.sort_values("total", ascending=False),
                 x_vars=crashes.columns[:-3], y_vars=["abbrev"],
                 height=10, aspect=.25)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h", jitter=False,
      palette="flare_r", linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")

# Use the same x axis limits on all columns and add better labels
g.set(xlim=(0, 25), xlabel="Crashes", ylabel="")

# Use semantically meaningful titles for the columns
titles = ["Total crashes", "Speeding crashes", "Alcohol crashes",
          "Not distracted crashes", "No previous crashes"]

for ax, title in zip(g.axes.flat, titles):

    # Set a different title for each axes
    ax.set(title=title)

    # Make the grid horizontal instead of vertical
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

Comment: Do you want to provide it or it to be deduced from the data for each column ?

Comment: I want to provide it. Just like in the example but for each column individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the loop over axes already there to set it individually.
For example, if you have a list of tuples (min, max) for each column in the right order (as `titles`) called `axes_xlims`,

```py
# e.g.,
axes_xlims = [(0, 25 + 2 * shift) for shift in range(len(titles))]

for ax, title, ax_xlim, in zip(g.axes.flat, titles, axes_xlim):

    # Set a different title and x limits for each axes
    ax.set(title=title, xlim=ax_xlim)

    # Make the grid horizontal instead of vertical
    ax.xaxis.grid(False)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
```